# Since Angular Material2 beta7, the style is broken for AOT setups

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2, angular-aot

Since the update of Angular Material2 beta7, the styling information seems to be broken for AOT setups, due to [this breaking change](https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/16b65e8d24198164da0b7f2171fdd17877d47048).

The field margins seem to be gone and the underline too. Everything seems to be lined up in one line.

[image]

Eventhough I have properly set the angular material prebuilt theme as described [here under step 4](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution.

This part here in the index.html wont work if you are using Angular with AOT (preferred way).

```
<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The Angular AOT compiler will not scrape in the header links of the index.html file. Instead, you need to copy the desired theme file from your node_modules folder and assign it to your default styling in your Angular app.

In my case, I had a themes.scss file in which I could simply import it like so:

```
@import "src/theme/deeppurple-amber";
```

Now it works. Good luck!